# Excel colour cell automatically according to cell content

Tags: excel, colors, customization, vba

In a Nutshell, what I would like to do is the equivalent of what you can do when you click the conditional formatting button but a bit more advanced.

Imagine you have a column with different values such as:

```
value1
value1
value2
value3
value3
value3
value1
```

etc..

What I want to do is assign a different colour for every different valueX.
I know it's easy to do via the conditional formatting button, but say I don't know how many values I have in total... Could be valueX to valueY or to valueZ. So Since I don't know how many different values I have in the column I would like excel to figure it out and assign a random colour for each value found accordingly.

I thought of using the RGB values and increment the RGB number for each value like 
valueX = FFFF00
valueY = FF0000
valuez = 000000
or something like that,

but that would require VB scripting or whatever scripting language excel is using nowadays and that's far beyond my personal knowledge of Excel.

Could somebody point me to the right direction? Would that be hard to do in a script?

Thanks very much

Comment: @Bluz - you should spend some time reviewing your previous questions and accept those that helped (click the check/tick mark next to the answer)

Comment: sorry...first time I hear about this..how do I accept answers?

Comment: Tim how do I do that ?

Comment: I am confused I am not sure what you're asking here. What previous answers do I need to accept? Can you provide some guidance please? Thanks

Comment: @JamesJenkins: Stackoverflow follows a very different model as compared to other forums. Here we don't force users to accept answers. If you feel it is a new user and doesn't know how to accept answers then there is a polite way of doing that. If they want they will do it on their own ;) If you do not wish to answer a question that is totally your choice but you cannot threaten someone like this :) You may want to read [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)

Comment: @Bluz: Please see the link in my above comment. See Chichiray's reply there. There is a link in his answer which explains everything :)

Comment: Sorry I don't want to start an argument here. I am happy to formally accept any answer provided to me, especially because the people who helped me here before had been extremely helpful.I simply need to know how to proceed.Sorry if I missed something here it wasn't intentional.If somebody tell me how to review and accept answers (I  looked at my previous questions again and can't see any "accept answer" button or whatever) I am happy to update them all asap.Thanks.

Comment: @Bluz: If there is no known number of records then yes, we can take a VBA approach here and increment the RGB like you mentioned. For that first store the values in a unique collection. The total records in the unique collection will tell you how many colors you will need. And then simply loop through them.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: `I was thinking about answering this, but I see that you don't accpet answers!` is an indirect threat;)

Comment: Guys, I've taken a few minutes to review my previous questions and accept answers. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing that out as I was completely oblivious with this. I thought voting up was all I needed to do to reward people.My questions are now updated.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Bluz, try this Condtitianl Formatting > Color Scales > Green Yellow Red.  This will automatcally set a slightly different color for each values.  If you want you can customize using "more Rules" under "Color Scales"

Comment: I actually tried that option before asking here and that's not what I need. The color scales are good enough for a range of values but not to identify a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this with VBA to conditionally color cells I select depending on their number value.

The easiest way would be like this:

```
Sub colorValues()

    For Each cell in Selection
        If cell.Value = "Value1" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 65535
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Value2" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 255
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Value3" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 13762516
       End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Very basic, but you could expand on it and add multiple colors. The number values are related to colors and I just picked random ones.

This example assumes a fixed number of values. If you wanted to dynamically color the cells that will be a little harder. You will have to create an array of the unique values in the selection and assign a color to each corresponding value.

Comment: That's exactly it! Would you have the code for what you explained here please? Thanks !